# How to get a parentNode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hey guy's just a quick question.

Im making a sortable, drag and drop system and i need it, when the user drags the message to the delete box it will **.remove();** and will disappear (well remove it) but the issue is it removes the little elements of the message like the subject, I want it to remove the whole div for example one of the **"message"** elements. So how do you get the parentNode of this which is the **message div**

It does refresh the messages so don't worry about the messages

The Code i have is

```
<div class="message 1" id="1">  // I want to remove this part and only this part
                    <ul id="8">
                        <li class="dragable" id="2">
                            <!-- Dragable -->

                        </li>
                        <li class="checkbox" id="4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="messagecheck1">
                        </li>
                        <li id="3"> 
                            <p> hi</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

js

```
$(".messageholder").sortable({          
        start: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.item).css("opacity", "0.25");
            draggable_sibling = $(ui.item).prev();
            $(".deletebox").show();
        },

        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".deletebox").hide();
            if (dropped) {
                if (draggable_sibling.length == 0)
                    $('.messageholder').prepend(ui.item);

                draggable_sibling.after(ui.item);
                dropped = false;
            }
            $(ui.item).css("opacity", "1.00");
        },
        update: function(event, ui){
            //Use's Xhr to save the position of the message
            var array = [];
            $(".messageholder div").each(function(e){
                 array.push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'json/save.php',
                data: ("data="+array)                           
            });

        }   


    }); 

        $(".refresh").click(function(){
            checkmessages();        
        });     

        $(".deletebox").droppable({         
                drop:function(event, ui){
                    dropped = true;                 
                    $(event.target.parentNode).closest('div').remove();


                    }               

        });     


        $(".messageholder").disableSelection();
```

Their are multiple elements with the same class name so i can't remove the **messages** class out in one line of code, I would have to select the element individually and remove it like that.

**Link** http://grubber.co.nz/messages/

Comment: What's so unclear about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, a quick google search should turn up `.parent()` : http://api.jquery.com/parent/

**Additional**

You can also use `.closest(selector)` if you need to use a selector to find an ancestor that's not the immediate parent : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: yer that was what i had at the start, like i said it removes its parent but i need to remove the parents parent...

Comment: Then use `.parent()` to get that element's parent

Comment: @Ryanc1256 - use `.closest("div.message")`.

Comment: Wow Thanks didn't really know about that .closest thing. Worked like a treat